# Update with Join PL/SQL with on/and condition - it tries to update all rows

Tags: sql, join, sql-update

I've looked through other answers and can't see this particular issue; I want to update a field where an internal code number is used to make sure the two customers are the same, and is the customer on a particular order.

When I run the below code, I get the warning "Are you sure you want to update all records" - and no, I don't!

---

```
UPDATE CustomerTable a
SET a.Text = 'text'
from a
join OrderTable b
on a.Customer = b.Customer
and b.Order = '10';
```

---

How do I get it to update that customer record and only that customer record?

Thank you!

Comment: What dbms you are using?

Comment: You mention PL/SQL in the title which is Oracle's language for writing stored procedures (your question only contains plain SQL, no PL/SQL though). But you can't be using Oracle as that statement is invalid for Oracle and would result in an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are repeating the table name in the `update`.  You want to phrase this as:

```
update CustomerTable ct
    set Text = 'text'
from OrderTable ot
where ot.Customer = ct.Customer and ot.Order = '10';
```

Or, in a structure that will work in almost any database:

```
update CustomerTable ct
    set Text = 'text'
where exists (select 1
              from OrderTable ot
              where ot.Customer = ct.Customer and
                    ot.Order = '10'
             );
```